# PHP HTML table - href links for database element that fills up table on following page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, href

I have a site that currently works as far as filtering options, so when someone selects a serial number from a dropdown and hits submit, my display.php page comes up and fills multiple html tables with the database elements corresponding to that serial number.

My new task is to fill the display page the same way but the means of getting there are different. Currently, if you select from drop down and hit submit, I post the submit button to the display.php page and the display page pulls the request, like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$query1 = "SELECT * 
           FROM staging 
           WHERE stageID = ".$_REQUEST['serialNumber'].";";
```

This checks the serial number selected against the database and pulls the entire record that's attached to it.

Now I have an html table on the main page and it fills with all the records in the database table. I would like to make each 'row' an html link with href and when that link is selected it pulls the display.php page and fills the tables with that values. The tables on display.php are already echoing the rows with the correct values from the database table so I just need a new way of populating from the link.

I know there's a way to use href on the elements, but the table is filled from the SQL statement result, like so:

```
<div class="dashboardTable">
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
<tr>
    <th>Work Order Packet</th>
    <th>Work Order Number</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Utility</th>
    <th>Service Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Serial No.</th>
</tr>

<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
?>
    <tr>
    <td><? echo $row['workOrderPacket'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['workOrderNum'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['date'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['utility'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['serviceName'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['address'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['serialNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?}?>
</table>
</div>
```

So, when someone clicks a link, is there a way to bring up my display.php page and check the database for a record that satisfies those 7 elements? Or even if I need to copy my display.php tables into a new file so that it doesn't confuse with the dropdown $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a regular link to the table, and alter you display page to allow either post or get:

```
<tr>
    <th>Work Order Packet</th>
    <th>Work Order Number</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Utility</th>
    <th>Service Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Serial No.</th>
    <th>View details</th>
</tr>

<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
?>
    <tr>
    <td><? echo $row['workOrderPacket'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['workOrderNum'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['date'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['utility'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['serviceName'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['address'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? echo $row['serialNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="/display.php?serialNumber=<? echo $row['serialNumber'];?>">view</a></td>
</tr>
<?}?>
```

display.php

```
//if(isset($_POST['submit']))
if(isset($_REQUEST['serialNumber']))
{

$query1 = "SELECT * 
           FROM staging 
           WHERE stageID = ".$_REQUEST['serialNumber'].";";
```

Also worth noting you are open to SQL injection, you should look into using prepared statements

Comment: Oh I didn't think of it that way, let me give that a try. Thank you!

Also, yes I had gone over prepared statements with someone previously and will do that in the future. This was for a project so I've been loose on some security and procedural issues, but I'll definitely take it into account, thank you!

Comment: I tried the view link row (which shows up and submits perfectly) and I had to change the path because i'm on a local server. I finally got it pulled but it just shows my connection successful message and a print out of the serial number selected. I commented out my post/submit line and put in your $_REQUEST line.

Comment: If all you changed is the if clause, then i have no idea why it wouldnt work, if the previous version did

Comment: I may have been unclear, I apologize. The previous (submit) version works from a different page (userSelection.php) where there is a dropdown and submit button. The above html table that shows all of the records is on a page called dashboard.php with no submit button. Let me add the code to the userSelection.php page and see if that works

Comment: Ok, I kept the IF statement you gave me on display.php and moved all the table code over to userSelect.php. The dropdowns and table show up properly but if I hit a view link it still goes to display.php and shows the connection message and echoes the serial number, but no tables

Comment: I refactored the href line a few times and even tried $_GET on display.php, but still no luck. Is it possible I need to change the variable on the href line?